# NSP module not recognized

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install nsp module globally using npm package management. I have used the command

```
npm install -g nsp
```

The installation process gets completed successfully and I see that nsp module folder gets created globally.

Now, if I try to fire the command,

```
nsp check
```

from my project directory, it does not recognize the command.

Just for the record, I am initiating the complete process using my administrator.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you see it using `npm list -g --depth=0`?

Comment: Yes, I see it with npm list -g --depth=0 command